# azure-notificationhubs- can't upload Sandbox certificate

Tags: ios, azure, ssl, xamarin.ios

I'm integating the push notification system on Xamarin.iOS. I've alrady gone over the documents Azure provided: [xamarin notification hubs ios push notification apns get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started)

However, when I try to upload the SSL certificate from Apple to Azure portal, the error happend.

```
{"error":{"message":"SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with APNS. 
  A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception...TrackingId:bac2701d-0185-453a-8ad8-43936dcaa6c9_M4SN1_M4SN1_G3,
 TimeStamp:3/11/2019 4:23:18 AM","code":"BadRequest"}}
```

Yes, the error can only be reproduced when I choose Sandbox.
For Production, the same certificate is OK to upload. 
That's very strange that I'm pretty sure the certificate is development, and the production SSL certificate is empty.

Can any one help? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: same here, can upload to production but failed to sandbox.

Comment: We're also having the same problem. No solution yet.

Comment: I am not using Xamarin or Azure, but I can verify that since midday Friday 3/8, I have been having the same problem with getting a developer certificate validated through the sandbox gateway. There are people in the Apple Developer forums having the same problem.

Comment: I attached a packet sniffer to my development machine and determined that the amount of data being returned from the sandbox server is vastly smaller than from the production server. I don't know if that means anything, but it seems to support the concern that there is a problem with the server.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think that's a Azure internal issue. I'm currently using the solution Kevin provided. Maybe you can have a try with it. : )

Comment: The hotfix has already been corrected by Microsoft, as follows: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5eb4c550-e3bf-4f04-ab82-8e153d069d4f/apns-dev-cert-upload-fails-400-bad-request-call-to-sspi-fails-with-sandbox-selected-succeeds-for?forum=notificationhubs For me, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem since yesterday.
The only alternative I've found is to turn round the bug/problem by using the "Token" way to connect Azure Notification Hub to APNS.

1. In your Azure Portal > Notification Hub > Apple (APNS), click "Token" under "Authentication Mode"
2. Fill the form as below (IDs and Token written here are not real data)
   [image]

If you are not familiar with retrieving those kind of information following the first part of [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-ios) could help.
It is very simple to transpose instructions to your Azure Notification Hub.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin. It works, you saved my day!

Comment: @William You can mark and upvote this answer if it is right and helps you.